# Padrão Singleton no Python

Tags: python, singleton

Estava vendo este [artigo](http://code.activestate.com/recipes/52558-the-singleton-pattern-implemented-with-python/) sobre como criar classes singleton em Python (dentre diversos outros), eu achei desnecessário tanta técnica de programação para uma coisa realmente simples. Claro que posso estar enganado. Mas se eu fizer isso, por exemplo

```
class TestSingleton:
    instance = None
    msg = "variável interna com dados padrão"

    def getInstance(self):
        if self.instance is None:
            self.instance = TestSingleton()
            return self.instance
        else:
            return self.instance
    def getConteudo(self):
        print self.msg
    def write(self, mensagem):
        self.msg = mensagem

obj = TestSingleton().getInstance()
obj.write("ola mundo")
obj.getConteudo()

obj2 = TestSingleton().getInstance()
obj2.getConteudo()

obj2.write("Que coisa !")
obj2.getConteudo() `
```

e depois fizer

```
obj = TestSingleton().getInstance()
obj.write()
```

Não seria a mesma coisa?

Comment: *"desnecessário tanta técnica de programação para uma coisa realmente simples"* - um singleton deve garantir que uma (e somente uma) instância da classe seja criada. Em ambientes multi-thread isso não é tão simples quanto parece, e toda esta técnica é necessária para garantir que não haverá mais que uma instância sendo criada. [Este artigo](https://taskinoor.wordpress.com/2011/04/18/singleton_multithreaded/) explica melhor porque não é tão simples assim. Ele usa exemplos em Java, mas os problemas relatados podem acontecer em qualquer linguagem.

Comment: Bem interessante o artigo. Vale notar que a especificação do Python garante o determinismo em alguns aspectos - em particular, o código que atribui uma referência à instancia a uma variável só será executado depois que toda a inicialização da instância estiver completa . Ou seja, em Python não acontece o maior fantasma previsto nesse artigo, que seria  a referência receber um endereço de memória que ainda não estaria inicializado.

Comment: Expandi a resposta para contemplar as preocupações desse artigo.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Existem várias formas de se ter um singleton no Python - se você não se importa de usar um método específico para obter o singleton, realmente pode ser uma das abordagens mais simples: ou seja "é possível" criar outra instância - mas se você pegar a referência à instancia sempre do mesmo lugar (o método `get_singleton`), você mantém a mesma instância.

Para que de fato "não seja possível" criar outra instância, seria necessário personalizar o método `__new__`, ou, eventualmente até fazer uso de uma metaclasse, se for necessário evitar que o método `__init__` seja chamado mais de uma vez (eu prefiro sem metaclasse, e com um  "if" dentro do `__init__`).

Mas - voltando ao seu exemplo - o único problema com ele é que o seu método `getInstance` é um método normal, de instância - então ele já depende de existir uma instância do objeto para ser chamado. E aí a coisa começa a dar nó. Mas se você transforma-lo num método de classe, então de fato ele vai criar uma única instância para a classe, (e você pode inclusive manter uma referência ao singleton dentro da própria classe, para não poluir o namespace do módulo):

```
class MeuSingletonManual:
    ...
    @classmethod
    def get_singleton(cls):
        if not hasattr(cls, "single_instance"):
            cls.single_instance = cls()
        return cls.single_instance

    ...
```

(Isso não vai criar um singleton para subclasses, se desejar isso, é só altrar o `if not hasattr(cls, "single_instance"):` para `if not "single_instance" in cls.__dict__` -  e pronto, um novo e único singleton será criado para cada subclasse de "MeuSingletonManual" onde o método "get_singleton" for chamado)

Em alguns casos, é realmente proibitivo que seja possível a criação de mais de uma instância - mesmo que por acidente, ou mesmo que temporariamente. Nesse caso, como está acima,  é melhor fazer um override do método `__new__`. Mais ainda, aí é possível cuidar para que a criação do singleton seja inclusive thread-safe, atendendo as preocupações do [artigo linkado](https://taskinoor.wordpress.com/2011/04/18/singleton_multithreaded/) nos comentários.

```
class MockLock:

    def __enter__(self):
        pass
    def __exit__(self, exception, exception_value, trace):
        pass

class Singleton:
    _instance = None
    _lock = threading.Lock()

    def __new__(cls):
        with cls._lock:
            if not cls._instance:
                instance = super().__new__(cls)
                instance.__init__()
                cls._instance = instance
                cls._lock = MockLock()
        return cls._instance

   def __init__(self):
       if self.__class__._instance:
           return
       ...
```

Pronto - o `if` dentro do `__init__` evita que seu corpo seja executado mais de uma vez pelo Python - e o código em  `__new__` assegura que a instanciação em si acontece só uma vez. 
A dancinha com o atributo `cls._lock` evita o problema relatado no artigo acima em relação ao custo de se obter um lock numa aplicação multithreading:  depois que o lock cumpriu sua função a primeira vez, um objeto "em branco" é colocado no lugar do lock - todas as checagens já
darão a instancia como existente, de qualquer forma - e não há mais perigo de uma race condition.

(numa nota paralela, em Python é costume usar snake_case para  métodos, e não lowerFirstCamelCase)

Comment: Bueno, agradeço demais por tuas explicações, obrigado!

Answer (score 5):

Não, nem perto. Se fosse a mesma coisa, quando você executasse `obj2.getConteudo()` a mensagem a ser exibida deveria ser "ola mundo", não a padrão, pois você alterou o valor deste atributo através de `obj` quando fez `obj.write("ola mundo")`. Se fossem *singleton*, os objetos deveriam, **necessariamente**, compartilhar exatamente o mesmo estado.

As duas instâncias não compartilharam o estado pelo motivo que `instance` é um tipo **imutável** (guarde este termo, será importante mais tarde). Mesmo que seja definido como um atributo de classe, ele será distinto entre todas as instâncias da mesma classe quando for modificado. Desta forma, quando ao criar a segunda instância, `self.instance` será nulo novamente, independente se foram, ou não, criadas instâncias anteriores.

A forma mais simples de contornar este problema seria utilizando como atributo de classe um tipo **mutável**, tal como uma lista ou dicionário. Por exemplo:

```
class TestSingleton:

    state = {
        'instance': None
    }

    msg = "variável interna com dados padrão"

    def getInstance(self):
        if self.state['instance'] is None:
            self.state['instance'] = TestSingleton()
        return self.state['instance']

    def getConteudo(self):
        print(self.msg)

    def write(self, mensagem):
        self.msg = mensagem
```

Assim, ao executar o código:

```
obj = TestSingleton().getInstance()
obj.write("ola mundo")
obj.getConteudo()  # ola mundo

obj2 = TestSingleton().getInstance()
obj2.getConteudo()  # ola mundo

obj2.write("Que coisa !")
obj2.getConteudo()  # Que coisa !

obj.getConteudo()  # Que coisa !
```

Ou seja, os objetos irão compartilhar o estado pois serão exatamente a mesma instância.

Ainda, esta solução seria ruim, pois desta maneira existiriam três instâncias distintas, sendo que duas serão utilizadas apenas retornar a terceira. Imagine que você controla vôos em um aeroporto está fazendo o embarque das pessoas em um avião; será apenas um voo, mas você exige que coloquem outras duas aeronaves para servir de "corredor", para os passageiros conseguirem acessar a aeronave que será utilizada na viagem. Consegue visualizar o custo disso tudo?

Para demonstrar isso, bastaria separar as operações de instância e execução do método `getInstance`, fazendo:

```
obj1 = TestSingleton()  # Aqui, obj1 seria a instância A
obj1 = obj1.getInstance()  # E aqui, obj1 receberia a instância C

obj2 = TestSingleton()  # Aqui, obj2 seria a instância B
obj2 = obj1.getInstance()  # E aqui, obj2 receberia a instância C
```

Neste ponto, iniciando o caminho para a solução ideal, é necessário responder uma pergunta: **eu realmente preciso de apenas um objeto, instância da classe, ou posso ter múltiplos objetos compartilhando o estado?**

No caso de poder compartilhar o estado com múltiplos objetos distintos, basta utilizar um atributo de classe com tipo mutável, semelhante como foi feito acima utilizando o dicionário. Por exemplo:

```
class Foo:
    shared = {
        'message': 'Olá mundo'
    }

    def getMessage(self):
        return self.shared['message']

    def setMessage(self, message):
        self.shared['message'] = message
```

Assim, poderia ser feito algo como:

```
a = Foo()
print(a.getMessage())  # Olá mundo
a.setMessage('Nova mensagem')

b = Foo()
print(b.getMessage())  # Nova mensagem

print('São o mesmo objeto:', b is a)  # São o mesmo objeto: False
```

Os dois objetos irão compartilhar o estado definido em `shared`, tanto que quando a mensagem é alterada em `a`, a mudança se reflete em `b`.

Já, se você precisa que sejam sempre o mesmo objeto (não apenas compartilhem o estado), você pode criar uma classe base definindo o método construtor `__new__`:

```
class Singleton:
    __instance = None
    def __new__(cls, *args, **kwargs):
        if Singleton.__instance is None:
            Singleton.__instance = super().__new__(cls)
        return Singleton.__instance
```

E, assim, você utilizar herança em sua classe:

```
class Foo(Singleton):
    def __init__(self, name):
        self.name = name
```

Por exemplo:

```
a = Foo("Anderson")
print(a.name)  # Anderson

b = Foo("Woss")
print(b.name)  # Woss

print(a.name)  # Woss

print('São o mesmo objeto:', b is a)  # São o mesmo objeto: True
```

Perceba que, ao definir `b` com um valor diferente, o atributo `name` de `a` também é alterado, pois serão o mesmo objeto.

Comment: Aquela leitura que o cara tem que parar para ler com gosto... obrigado por seu tempo e explicação!